# Get data from a table in sql to a textview in android studio from a specific row

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I have a table in ms sql this table contains FName and FInfo i want to get th FInfo according to the FName like if the FName in the app is equal to john it gets the FInfo of john in the same row.

i have tried everything including query's and Result set but it didn't work out for me.

here is my code:

```
public class InsideFamily extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView inf;
    private boolean success = false; // boolean
    private ConnectionClass connectionClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inside_family);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


            inf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thefamilyinf);


            connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();



           SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
            orderData.execute("");
        }


        private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            String msg = "No Data Found";
            ProgressDialog progress;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(InsideFamily.this, "Synchronising",
                        "Please Wait...", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
            {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN();
                            if (conn == null) {
                                msg = "Please Check Your Connection";
                                success = false;
                            } else {

                                String gettingfam = getIntent().getStringExtra("defamily");
                                String query = "SELECT * FROM family where FName='" + gettingfam + "'";
                                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


                                if (rs != null) {
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        try {


                                            inf.setText((rs.getString("FInfo")));

                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    msg = "Found";
                                    success = true;
                                } else {
                                    msg = "No Data found!";
                                    success = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                            msg = writer.toString();
                            success = false;

                        }
                    }
                });

                return msg;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String
                                                 msg)
            {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(InsideFamily.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (success == false) {
                } else {
                    try {

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                }
            }

        }

}
```

the errors i get is that it brings a toast for me saying that "No Data Found!"

which means that that the result set equals null how can i fix it??

Comment: I was reading it wrong... Sample data and what value you are passing would be good. Also, does the `Select` work in `SSMS`?

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand you can you be more clear?!

Comment: If you use SQL Server Management Studio and open a query window, does this `SELECT * FROM family where FName= 'JOE'` return any results?

Comment: If you can post sample data and the actual value you are passing to the query would help us to help you resolve this.

Comment: no it doesn't return any result i just want to get the info according to the name and the table contains FName column ,and FInfo column and then lets say there is a row containing "JOE" and the info is "he is a good man" in the app it gets the name (Joe) but how can i get the info(he is a good man) in a textview

Comment: am posting arabic names

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

the wrong was in the query
because its nvarchar i have to wright

```
"SELECT * FROM family WHERE FName = (N'" +dta+ "')"
```

rather than

```
"SELECT * FROM family where FName='" + gettingfam + "'"
```